# php echo interfere's with echo json_encode

Tags: php, json, ajax

So here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
$array = ['asd','asd2'];
header("Content-type: application/json");

echo json_encode($array);


?>
```

here's my ajax:

```
var adat = [];
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
url: 'test.php',
success: function(data){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
        adat.push(data[i]);
    }
}
})

console.log(adat);
```

This works totally fine, i get the array values in my adat array BUT if i add another echo to the php file like this, it stops working:

```
<?php
$array = ['asd','asd2'];
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo ("text");
echo json_encode($array);


?>
```

Comment: This is most likely happening because that's malformed JSON; you can only send a valid JSON string with a content type of JSON

Comment: It is not JSON anymore. You don't need to set that `header` either. Just set `xhr.responseType = 'json';`.

Comment: As has been pointed out `text ["asd","asd2"]` is not valid JSON..  Maybe you want `$array = ['text' => ['asd','asd2']];` or similar, not sure.

Comment: Thank you aswell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're injecting `text` into your JSON output.  This of course breaks anything trying to read JSON.

It's no different than if you took any other file and injected garbage data into it.  Whatever is expecting a specific format is going to fail.

Comment: Where should i put other echo's than? For example i want to echo out an error message on the page.

Comment: @DánielMozsár You need to pick what the response format is.  If it's JSON, then include your error message in the data you serialize as JSON.  If it's text or HTML, then you can't also have JSON output.